# Finding sentences that contain one of an array of keywords using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7

I want to go through a .txt file and only keep the sentences that contain one or more of a list of keywords.

After that I want to go through the remaining text once more with another list of keywords and  repeat the proces.

The result I want to save in that .txt, the rest can be deleted.

I'm new to Python (but loving it!) so don't worry about hurting my feelings by, you're free to assume little knowledge on my side and dumb it down a bit :)

This is what I have so far:

```
import re

f = open('C:\\Python27\\test\\A.txt')

text = f.read()
define_words = 'contractual'
print re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s[^.]*\.)" % define_words,text)
```

And that works in so far that it filters out any sentence with 'contractual' in it. If I'd put 'contractual obligation' there it will filter out the sentences that have those two words next to each other.

What I'm stuck at is how do I change that into an array of words that will all be considered seperately of each other? Like 'contractual', 'obligation', 'law', 'employer' etc etc

EDIT regarding applepi's answer:

I've done some testing with a small test:

"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

New line.

Yet another nice new line."

I only get a sentence if I put 2 words in that sentence in the string. Like ['quick', 'brown']

OUTPUT: ['T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'q', 'u', 'i', 'c', 'k', ' ', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'x', 'y', ' ', 'j', 'u', 'm', 'p', 's', ' ', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'z', 'y', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'g', '.']

So ['quick', 'another'] comes up with nothing.

['Yet', 'another'] will come up with:

OUTPUT: [' ', '\n', '\n', 'Y', 'e', 't', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' ', 'n', 'i', 'c', 'e', ' ', 'n', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'e', '.']

Comment: You may want to look into the RegEx [`or`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use list comprehension?

```
print [sent for sent in text.split('.') 
        if any(word in sent for word in define_words.split()) ]
```

or if you change define_words for list of strings:

```
# define_words = ['contractual', 'obligations']
define_words = 'contractual obligations'.split()

print [sent for sent in text.split('.') 
        if any(word in sent for word in define_words) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def init_contains_useful_word(words_to_search_for):

    def contains_useful_word(sentence):
        return any(map(lambda x: x in sentence, words_to_search_for))

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

sentences = text.split(".")

for words in list_of_lists:
    contains_useful_word = init_contains_useful_word(words)

    sentences = filter(contains_useful_word, sentences)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(sentences.join(" "))
```

actually, you can replace the contains useful word with your re operator if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment (I don't have enough reputation), so this answer isn't technically an answer.

I am not very familiar with regex, but assuming your `re.findall()` is successful, you can use the following code:

```
import re, itertools
from collections import Counter
f = open('C:\\Python27\\test\\A.txt')

text = f.read()
everything = []
define_words = ['contractual', 'obligation', 'law', 'employer']
for k in define_words:
    everything.append(re.findall(r"([^.]*?%s[^.]*\.)" % k,text))

everything = list(itertools.chain(*everything))
counts = Counter(everything)
everything = [value for value, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
everything = list(itertools.chain(*everything))
print everything
```

This loops over the array list and adds the values to a list, making a list of lists. Then I keep only the duplicates (the good values), and I convert the list of lists into one list.

**ERROR:** the real error was that everything was a list of lists, which `Counter(everything)` did not allow. Thus, I have stripped it before the `Counter()`.

Comment: My comment would just be, *use a `for` loop*

Comment: Looks really promising for something that is not an answer :) I get this error though: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/PythonProjects/test.py", line 11, in <module> counts = Counter(all) File "C:\Python27\lib\collections.py", line 450, in init self.update(iterable, **kwds) File "C:\Python27\lib\collections.py", line 532, in update self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sorry, change `all` to something else, like `everything`, it seems `all` is a built-in function :)

Comment: Actually, that *wasn't* the error, I have specified the real one in my answer.

Comment: I get a long list of single characters: [' ', 'F', 'a', 'c', 't', 'o', 'r', 's', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'i', 'c', 'h', ' ', 'l', 'e', 'd', ' ', 't', 'o', ' '] (it's longer then this :)) Good thing is it only happens when the define words has at least one word that's in the file. The list of single characters does change based on what keywords I put in.

Comment: Haha, now I look at my comment above again I suddenly see words. "Factors which led to" So it looks like it's adding all the characters of a sentence seperately. I'll check if the correct words are in there.

Comment: Edited my question in regards to your solution, easier to show what's going on.